# UWP: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

This is the error: (it is not complete but this is what VS gives me)

> XDG0062 System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has
>   been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
>   Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException: The text associated with
>   this error code could not be found.
>
> No matching constructor found on type 'SMPlayer.MediaControl'. [Line:
>   163 Position: 25]    at
>   Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri
>   resourceLocator, ComponentResourceLocation componentResourceLocation) 
>   at SMPlayer.MediaControl.InitializeComponent()    at
>   SMPlayer.M    SMPlayer    MainPage.xaml   151

However, my MediaControl does have a constructor, which is defined [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Controls/MediaControl.xaml.cs). (Sorry for posting the link instead of the code). And `MediaControl.g.i.cs` does not have Line 163.

Nonetheless, my project still compiles and runs correctly even with that error. And my MediaControl is displayed properly.

What is wrong?

Comment: The error is not from the compiler but from the XAML Designer within VisualStudio.

Comment: So how should I fix that @KlausGütter

Comment: Don't know. I just wanted to point out that your code is probably fine, but the VS XAML Designer somehow picked up the wrong metadata. What might help: reboot, delete obj and bin directories, clear any Visual Studio caches (somewhere below %localappdata%)

Comment: Ha, that works! Thanks for helping me remove another annoying "warning" :) @KlausGütter

Comment: @KlausGütter Damn it comes up again...